# How to list users by role in one page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to list users by role in one page. Now I only can list one role 
I defined it in controller 
`@users = User.where(role: 'vip' )`
But I want to list users which role is vip or admin in the same page with two tables. If you want to know more informatian, please let me know. Thank you very much for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may just do

```
@vip_users = User.where(role: 'vip')
@admin_users = User.where(role: 'admin')
```

and then use these two variables to list both categories in your view, like this:

```
<% @vip_users.each do |user| %>
  # Create your table with vip users here
<% end %>

<% @admin_users.each do |user| %>
  # Create your table with admin users here
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thx, your answer is very helpful.It solves my problem~ :)